# Spark: How to use a temp table to filter the result when use sqlContext.sql and partitioned by columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have code below

```
    DataFrame idDF = sparkHelper.loadIds();
    List<String> idList = idDF.javaRDD().map(row -> {
                Integer id = row.getAs("id");
                return Integer.toString(id);
            }).collect();
    String ids = String.join(",", idList);

    String sql = "(SELECT a.* from TableA a where a.id in (" + ids + ")) as tl";

    Map<String,String> props = getDbConnectionProps(); // basic connections set up
    props.put("dbtable", sql);
    props.put("fetchSize", "100000");
    props.put("partitionColumn", "col1");
    props.put("lowerBound", "1");
    props.put("upperBound", "1000");
    props.put("numPartitions", "10");

    DataFrame aDF = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
```

The benefit of doing this is that the I can specify some properties when I query the table A, e.g. partition column.

However, now the idea to build the var ids is considered to be replaced by a temp table that can be reused in many data loading sqls. I am wondering if there is a way to do that and keep the data partition the same way as above.

Thought 1: I was thinking of doing this

```
    DataFrame idDF = sparkHelper.loadIds();
    idDF.registerTempTable("temp_table_ids");
    DataFrame aDF = sqlContext.sql("select a.* from TableA a inner join temp_table_ids ti on a.id = ti.id");
```

Now, my question is how can I make sure the aDF is partitioned by column col1 just like the current code did. If we load to aDF first and then repartition it, I think it is not as efficient as we pass in the partition column info when we load the data as we did now. Am I right?

Thought 2: If above way is not achievable, can I actually create a temporary table in mysql database and use it in hive-context data loading? Will this doable? I gave a try with creating a temp table tempTableA

```
sqlContext.sql("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTableA");
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTableA (id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(accountId))");
```

and use it in the "current" code (replacing the ids string by inner join). However, it cannot be recognized. The error I got is `cannot recognize input near 'DROP' 'TEMPORARY' 'TABLE' in ddl statement`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How did you create the mysql temporary table, and what is the error message that spark uses the temporary table?

Comment: @过过招 Please see updated question.